# Measure of the Boundary

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A = [0,1/2]$U$[1/2,1]$  What is the Lebesgue measure of A?  What is the measure of the boundary of A?

Attempt:

We can consider A to be [0,1] to obtain mA = 1.  The boundary of A consists of the points {0,1/2,1} and hence has measure zero.

Comment: Correct, except that since $A=[0,1]$, $\partial A = \{0,1\}$.

Comment: What if we now consider only the irrationals in the set above?

Comment: Then the measure of the set would stay $1$, but the boundary set would become the intersection of the closure of the irrationals and the closure of the rationals in $[0,1]$. Since both are dense, the boundary set would thus be $[0,1]$ with measure $1$.

Comment: Would we not have an issue merging the two unioned intervals since rationals are taken out?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by that.

Comment: We are still talking about the boundary as the intersection of the closure of irrationals and of rationals in [0,1] but don't we have to talk about both sets separately now?

Comment: That doesn't matter, if we define $I(A)$ to be the irrationals in set $A$ and $R(A)$ to be the rationals in set $A$, then $I([0,1]) = I([0,\frac{1}{2}])\cup I([\frac{1}{2},1])$ and $R([0,1]) = R([0,\frac{1}{2}])\cup R([\frac{1}{2},1])$.

Comment: Thank you very for clearing that up, I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that $$\partial A=\{0,1\},$$ you're absolutely right.

Comment: What if we now consider the irrationals in the set above?

Comment: Well, the set of **rationals** in $A$ is countable, and disjoint from the set of irrationals in $A$. Since $A$ is the union of those two disjoint set, then use additivity of measure and the fact that countable sets are of measure $0$ to conclude that the set of irrationals in $A$ is of measure $1$.